# Call Child of Component with ignoring parent at Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I have Component schema like picture below,
currently when i wan to call table from app.vue i must write

```
this.$refs.list.$refs.table
```

is There any way to ignore $refs.list that i can call table directly? like

```
this.$refs.table
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a transparent ref It is impossible.

Refs are used to call methods on nested instances. In order not to go deep you should have a method in the list that will call the method in the table.

you need to do composition in a component where a nested ref is needed, this is usually not done. `getA (). getB (). doSomething ();`